# c# ignoring { in strings

Tags: c#, json, string, declaration

I'm trying to learn c# Json.net and I want to create a JSON multiline string that includes string declarations, but the first curly bracket which is meant to be part of the JSON dictionary is including itself in the declaration. It errors me on the 'name', if anyone can please give me a solution that would be great.
here is the code.

```
            string Name = "'Name'";
            string Is_Airing = "True";
            string Genre_One = "'Yes'";
            string Genre_Two = "'No'";

            string Json_String = $@"{
              'Name': '{Name}',
              'Is_Airing': {Is_Airing},
              'Genres': [
                '{Genre_One}',
                '{Genre_Two}'
              ]
            }";
```

Comment: Please don't use string interpolation for JSON serialisation. Use a proper API for that, e.g. Newtonsoft JSON.

Comment: Or even the built in one; [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-5.0) .

Comment: @Sweeper `I'm trying to learn c# Json.net` sounds to me like OP is using json.net which is Newtonsoft - http://json.net/

Comment: Even if this immediate problem is fixed, you'll still have more problems: JSON strings are surrounded by double quotes, not single quotes. You'll also have to escape the strings in case it has things like backslashes and quotes... [Please learn how to do this properly](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)

Comment: @RandRandom that's not JSON.NET code. That's string interpolation. If this is an attempt to create a test string, it would be a lot easier to just write that string

Answer (score 3):

If your heart is set on DIY, double up the brackets to escape `{{`, but you're really [doing a poor job of] reinventing the wheel compared to using a serializer and chucking something like an anonymous or proper type into it:

```
//newtonsoft
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
  Name, //gets name of property from name of variable
  Is_Airing = MyIsAiringVariableName, //specifies name of property in anonymous type
  Genres = new []{
     Genre_One,
     Genre_Two
  }
});
```

> `'Name': '{Name}',`

JSON uses double quotes, by the way.. And typically uses camelCase names. Usign a serializer will ensure better compliance with standard JSON ("be strict in what you send and liberal in what you accept")

For more control over how the output JSON appears, you set options on the serializer (such as passing `Formatting.Indented` as the second argument to SerializeObject), or decorate your properties with attributes

The Newtonsoft documentation is quite comprehensive and includes useful samples to get you going: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm